# Applet Background Flashing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, background, applet

I have made a simple test applet that has a red background and a few buttons. When I run the applet (its at http://nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/GUIApplet.html) the buttons show up, but the red doesn't. When I click the applet, sometimes part of the background flashes red. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Here is the applet code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet.*;

public class GUIApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

/** Initializes the applet GUIApplet */
public void init() {
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
}

/** This method is called from within the init() method to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 300));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 300));
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 300));
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
    getContentPane().add(jTextField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 170, -1, -1));

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(17, 90, -1, -1));

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    getContentPane().add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 90, -1, -1));
}// </editor-fold>


// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration

}
```

Comment: The overridden `paint()` method does nothing that would not have been done if it had *not* been overridden.  But take it out even ignoring that fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the background of the JApplet's contentPane, not the JApplet itself since it is the contentPane that actually holds the components and that is being displayed. Call `getContentPane().setBackground(...);` in your init method instead of the naked `setBackground(...)` call.

Comment: +1, beat me by 4 minutes (was I really that slow in typing?). Just want to add you should NOT override the paint(...) method.

Comment: Because I'm in netbeans I can't edit the initComponents method manually so I added a panel and changed its background. Now, the applet is blank and won't show anything. I even changed it back to the original and it didn't work.

Comment: I forgot that I had changed the layout to absolute from null. I changed it back and now the buttons show up.

Comment: As you are using NetBeans, you can examine the Local History to see.